# Prove $X\cap g_1Y\cap g_2Z \not = \varnothing$

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Let $X, Y, Z \leqslant G$, a group such that the following property holds: $$
> X(Y\cap Z)= XY\cap XZ. 
> $$
>   Now let $g_1,g_2 \in G$ such that $X\cap g_1Y \not = \varnothing, X\cap g_2Z \not = \varnothing, g_1Y\cap g_2Z \not = \varnothing.$
>
> Prove $X\cap g_1Y\cap G_2Z \not = \varnothing$

Can anybody give me a hint?

I've tried all sorts of things, but nothing seems to work out. I tried choosing an element from $g_1Y\cap g_2Z$ which implies $g_1y_1= g_2z_2 \Rightarrow z_2 = g_2^{-1}g_1y_1$, and similir things for the other intersections and then combining this in some way, but to no avail.

I don't see how $X(Y\cap Z) = XY\cap XZ$ can be used? I know that $Y\cap Z \leqslant G$ but I'm not sure what to do with it. Perhaps something like:

Since $Y\cap Z \subseteq X$ implies $Y\cap Z \subseteq XY \cap XZ \Rightarrow Y\cap Z \subseteq XY$ and for $XZ$ as well..

A hint would be very usefull...

Comment: Does the property hold for any three subsets of $G$, or just the specific $X,Y,Z$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Justify and combine the following bits. Below $x_i\in X, y_i\in Y$ and $z_i\in Z$ for all $i$.

1. There exist $x_1,y_1$ such that $g_1=x_1y_1$.
2. There exist $x_2,z_2$ such that $g_2=x_2z_2$.
3. There exist $y_3,z_3$ such that $g_1y_3=g_2z_3$.
4. The product $u=x_1y_1y_3=x_2z_2z_3$ is an element of $XY\cap XZ$. (you may want to stop reading at this point, and try to figure out the rest)
5. There exist $x\in X$ and $w\in Y\cap Z$ such that $u=xw$.
6. $x\in X\cap g_1Y\cap g_2Z$.

Comment: Trying to leave bits and pieces for you to do, but I'm not sure I did a good job there. Getting to 4 is sorta revealing, but I didn't see a way to just hint at it.